# apache user directory access permission denied

Tags: apache-2.2, chmod, permissions

I've run `chmod 777` on `/home/cache/`, however the apache user is still unable to write to it.  My php script is writing to this directory but got a permission denied error and don't know why.

`ls -ld cache` shows:

> drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root 69632 Aug 24 17:04 cache/

`ls -ld /home` shows:

> drwxr-xr-x. 19 root root 4096 Aug 24 18:30 /home

Comment: Also post the error log here?

Comment: And what is the exact error message that the php function returns?

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner permission of the `/home/cache/` to "apache user" by running the command:

> chown apache /home/cache/

After that ensure selinux is turned off in your system.  You can run `setenforce 0` to turn selinux off.